# Why there is no "Add subject" in MMS messages?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, mms

I've been waiting for to long for this option and clearly, Microsoft is decided to not include in their plans. Do I've missed some explanation?? Seem like I've missed the lesson.

Comment: Uh... Do you mean "MMS"? SMS does not have a subject.

Comment: It really starts like SMS, I think so, so subject or whatever which make change the message type is irrelevant for me. but it's a valid and understandable point. thanks, I'll change it.

Comment: Where have you seen the notion of subjects for MMS messages?

Comment: Android and iOS both allow this feature. it is true that it makes no sense, but it is easier than choose another option. Please, use common sense.

Comment: @RowlandShaw I'm pretty sure it is actually a thing; I've seen some SO questions on it, and when I send or receive MMS it often says "NoSubject".